# vertical scrollviewer bug in windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a page with lots of data so I need to use scrollviwer because of overflow items.
In this page I have something like list view (I made that) that has lots of items so I need to use scrollviewer for this list too.
So I have 2 vertical scrollviewer:
1) for all page items.
2) for My list view.
I made this app for windows phone 8.1. When I want to scroll in my list view I cant because of all page scrollviewer.
How can I solve that?
My code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerAllPage" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="White" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomMode="Disabled">
            <Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="StackMain" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Collapsed">
            ...
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewerReport" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Margin="32,0" Background="White" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomMode="Disabled" PointerPressed="ScrollViewerReport_PointerPressed">
                            <Grid x:Name="StackPanelReport" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation = "Vertical">
                                    ...
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation = "Vertical">
                                    ...
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation = "Vertical">
                                    ...
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Orientation = "Vertical">
                                    ...
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

I am sorry for bad English.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the XAML look like?

Comment: You have added your listview inside stack panel . so just add listview inside grids and grid must have fixed height

Comment: I can't do that because I need Orientation="Horizontal". grid doesn't have it. Can you help in other way?

Comment: Normally scrollviewer needs to have fixed heights, so use grid and rows of with fixed height instead of stack panel

Comment: grid can be divided in to columns

Comment: thanks for helping. I changed it and use fixed size but It's hard to get second scrollviewer (may list veiw) you can get it but most of the time you get first scrollviewer (all page). I want to make slide bar and use that for scrolling. What can I do? can you help me?